# Prevent server call when model is already loaded and won't change

Tags: ember.js

I have a route which makes server calls for 2 models. There is one of those model which isn't gonna change when someones uses the app. The problem I have is that ember keeps making server calls to fill the subuser model (which doesn't change) when I need to update the conversations model.

What is the best way to prevent that? I am using the method findAll to retrieve datas for the subusers model.

Server calls to subuser are made everytime I filter the conversations model :

http://gyazo.com/ab90efd97a37aa96798d12192785f9c3

Here is my router :

```
App.Router.map(function(){

//Routing list to raw namespace path
    this.resource('conversations', { path : '/' }, function() {
    this.resource('conversation', { path : '/:conversation_id'});
    });

});
```

Here is my route :

```
App.ConversationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

model: function(params){

        return this.store.find('conversation', { status : params.status});
},

setupController: function(controller, model){

    this._super(controller.model);

    controller.set('subusers', this.store.findAll('subuser'));
},

queryParams: {
    status: {
        refreshModel: true
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setupController` hook is going to be called every time the route is entered and needs to place the model on the controller. And because you're using a `findAll` call, Ember can't cache that (how is it supposed to know there isn't any new data?).

You need to either change your `findAll` call to something that is cacheable or cache the call yourself somehow. This might work:

```
var subusers = null;

App.ConversationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);

        if (!subusers) {
            subusers = this.store.findAll('subuser');
        }

        controller.set('subusers', subusers);
    }
});
```

Comment: Working like a charm. I just put your subusers variable as a property in the route like this :   subusers: null, etc. Thank you!